# Spring boot with mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

I need to test service method with mocking dao. And also I need to test dao method to know if a method works correctly.But I can't integrate the mockito with spring boot. If I use `MockitoJUnitRunner` first test works if I use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` second test works. I also tried using `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`, but it doesn't work either.

```
//SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
//MockitoJUnitRunner
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BookServiceTests {

    @Mock
    private BookDao bookDao;
    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao2;
    private List<Book> listOfBooks;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMostPopularBooksInService() {
        fillListOfBooks();
        when(bookDao.selectMostPopularBooks(3, 3)).thenReturn(listOfBooks);
        assertEquals(3, bookService.getMostPopularBooks(0, 3).size());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSelectMostPopularBooks() {
        fillDBByBooks();
        List<Book> listOfPopularBooks = bookDao2.selectMostPopularBooks(0, 3);
        assertEquals(3, listOfPopularBooks.size());
        assertEquals("Марсианинн", listOfPopularBooks.get(0).getName());
    }

    private void fillListOfBooks() {
        Writer writer = new Writer(3, "Джек", "Лондон", "...", null);
        listOfBooks = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfBooks.add(new Book(6, "Зов предков", 1990, writer, "...",
                10, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Genre(1, "Психология")))));
        listOfBooks.add(new Book(8, "Зов предков", 1990, writer, "...",
                25, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Genre(1, "Психология")))));
        listOfBooks.add(new Book(10, "Зов предков", 1990, writer, "...",
                35, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Genre(1, "Психология")))));
    }

    private void fillDBByBooks() {
        Writer writer = new Writer(28, null, null, null, null);
        entityManager.persist(new Book(0, "Огонь и вода", 1990, writer, "...",
                105, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Genre(1, "Психология")))));
        entityManager.persist(new Book(0, "Солнце", 1990, writer, "...",
                150, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Genre(1, "Психология")))));
        entityManager.persist(new Book(0, "Космос", 1990, writer, "...",
                200, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Genre(1, "Психология")))));
        entityManager.persist(new Book(0, "Марсианин", 1990, writer, "...",
                225, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Genre(1, "Психология")))));
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read through the Spring Boot testing documentation?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: Yes. Apparently, I missed something. And I know that it's not good to test like I did, but just for example sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Your context configuration annotation is missing from the test class so you wont have any spring container support or autowiring there. It should be something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {MyApplicationConfig.class}
)

public class MyTestClass
```

Second, I wouldn't mix mocked beans and autowired ones in the same test class. I am not sure that is even possible. I suggest you split your tests into two classes. One with the real DAOs and the context configuration available, and the other class with only pure mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ContextConfiguration annotation is not obligatory as SpringBootTest will try to find existing configuration by itself (however as far as I remember it will throw an exception if there are more than 1 context configurations available).

Moreover, there is no problem using mock beans and autowired ones, here is an example:

```
@RunWith ( SpringRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClassTest {

    @Autowire
    private RealBean realBean;

    @MockBean
    private BeanYouWantToMock mockedBean;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
    }
```

However, **DO NOT** use @InjectMocks annotation, @MockBean means that you are replacing real bean in context with mocked one, so you don't need to inject it somewhere, the spring context will do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer) It was helpful